# select all text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

i need to select all text in my html code and surround them with `<span>` tag in JavaScript

convert this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1><span id="text">Heading</span></h1>
<p><span id="text">paragraph.</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Firstly, why would you ever need this? And secondly, duplicate `id` attributes are invalid. You need to use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your text with this fonction :

```
$(selector).wrapInner( "<span class=\"text\"></div>");
```

where selector target the tag you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('html').prependTo('<script>');
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
hi
</body>
</html>
```